# how to update a username in simplemembership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am building an MVC4 application.  The application users the email address as the username.
I have a situation where a user might change their email address, which means I need the system to be able to change his username..

is that possible with MVC4 and simplemebership?

So i want to change an existing users username to a new one

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership does not provide the methods to update a user from the WebSecurity API. You have to use Entity Framework to do this.

Option one is to use the [SimpleSecurity Project](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) which provides an extended implementation of WebSecurity.  Here is a snippet from unit test in the SimpleSecurity Project that tests updating a user, where the username is modified.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUpdateUser()
    {
        string username = "jdoe";
        string password = "password";
        string token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password, "jdoe@gmail.com", false);
        bool validated = WebSecurity.ValidateUser(username, password);
        Assert.IsTrue(validated, "Failed validation of user.");
        //Get user for update
        var user = WebSecurity.GetUser(username);
        //Change the user name
        username = "jdoe2";
        user.UserName = username;
        //Update the user information
        WebSecurity.UpdateUser(user);
        //Make sure we can still validate them
        validated = WebSecurity.ValidateUser(username, password);
        Assert.IsTrue(validated, "Failed validation of user after update.");

    }
```

The second option is to explore the source code in SimpleSecurity to see how it was implemented and replicate it.  You can [get the source code here](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). You can step through the unit test in **SimpleSecurity.UnitTest**.